# Python: print dictionary keys and values individually

Tags: python-3.x

I'm wondering: how do you print the keys or the values individually from a dictionary in a function?

**Example .txt file**

```
 00000000;Pikachu Muchacho;region1
 11111111;SoSo good;region2
 22222222;Marshaw williams;region3
 33333333;larry Mikal Carter;region3
```

**Code**

```
test_file = open("test.txt", "r")
customer = {}
def dictionary():
    for line in test_file:
        entries = line.split(";")
        key = entries[0]
        values = entries[1]
        customer[key] = values

def test():
    print(customer)
    print(customer[key])

def main():
    dictionary()
    test()

main()
```

Comment: customer.keys() and customer.values() gives you all the keys and all of the values

Comment: I am not downvoting but this is my sincere advice that you make a little more effort before asking such questions.

Comment: I did give it effort. That is why i'm asking because i tried several different approaches at it and i did not figure it out. Before you give your opinion give it a little thought. I'm new to the language and coding in general.

Answer (score 0):

As @jamesRH commented, you can use `customer.keys()` and `customer.values()`:

```
test_file = open("test.txt", "r")
customer = {}
def dictionary():
    for line in test_file:
        entries = line.split(";")
        key = entries[0]
        values = entries[1]
        customer[key] = values

def test():
    # Print all the keys in customer
    print(customer.keys())

    # Print all the values in customer
    print(customer.values())

def main():
    dictionary()
    test()

main()
```

This gives the output:

```
['00000000', '22222222', '33333333', '11111111']
['Pikachu Muchacho', 'Marshaw williams', 'larry Mikal Carter', 'SoSo good']
```

Your original code causes an error because `key` is not within the scope of `test()`.

Comment: Thanks. What if I wanted to output them vertically like in a column with just the entries only and nothing else attached with it